# PHP Image Deletion Script Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I have a gallery script that I am adding a delete function to. I have everything implemented, but my files are not being deleted.

This is my gallery script which also includes a submit button to delete the image:

```
<?php
$directory = "images/gallery/";
$filecount = 0;
$files = glob($directory . "*");
if ($files){
 $filecount = count($files);
}
echo "<h2>Gallery - Click To Enlarge</h2><h3>$filecount Images</h3>";
?>
</div>
<div id="galleryImages">
<?php
$folder = 'images/gallery/';
$filetype = '*.*';    
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);    
$total = count($files);    
$per_page = 15;    
$last_page = (int)($total / $per_page);    
if(isset($_GET["page"])  && ($_GET["page"] <=$last_page) && ($_GET["page"] > 0) ){
    $page = $_GET["page"];
    $offset = ($per_page + 1)*($page - 1);      
}else{
    $page=1;
    $offset=0;      
}    
$max = $offset + $per_page;    
if($max>$total){
    $max = $total;
}       
    show_pagination($page, $last_page);        
    for($i = $offset; $i< $max; $i++){
        $file = $files[$i];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
        $filename = $path_parts['filename'];        
        echo '<div class="thumbImage">'."\n";
        echo '<a href="'. $file .'" data-featherlight="image">'."\n";
        echo '<img src="'. $file .'" width="200px" alt="" />'."\n";
        echo '</a>'."\n";
         if(isset($_SESSION['usr']) && isset($_SESSION['pswd'])){
          echo'<span class="deleteImage">'."\n";
          echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$file.'" name="delete_file" id="delete_file" />'."\n";
          echo '<input type="button" value="Delete image" onclick="delete_image()"/>'."\n";
          echo '</span>'."\n";
          }
        echo '</div>'."\n";        
    }        
    show_pagination($page, $last_page);
    function show_pagination($current_page, $last_page){
    echo '<div class="galleryPagination">';
    if( $current_page > 1 ){
        echo ' <a href="?page='.($current_page-1).'"> Previous Page </a> ';
    }
    if( $current_page > 1 ){
        echo ' <a href="?page=1"> First Page </a> ';
    }
    if( $current_page != $last_page ){
    echo ' <a href="?page='.$last_page.'"> Last Page </a> ';
    }
    if( $current_page < $last_page ){
        echo ' <a href="?page='.($current_page+1).'"> Next Page </a> ';  
    }
    echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

My Jquery/Ajax to submit the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delete_image()
{
  var status = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");  
  if(status==true)
  {
    var file = $("#delete_file").val();
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"scripts/php/deleteImage.php",
      data:{file:file},
      success(html){
       ohSnap('Image has been deleted', 'red');
      }
    });
  }
 }
</script>
```

And the contents of deleteImage.php

```
<?php
 if ( array_key_exists ('delete_file', $_POST ) ) {
       $filename = $_POST['delete_file'];
       if ( file_exists ( $filename ) ) {
           unlink( $filename );
           echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
       }
  }
?>
```

I believe I know what the problem is but I am unsure. When my php generate the thumbnail images it has to include the image directory as well so the image is linked. It does the same in the submit button for deletion.

For example this is one of the outputted images:

```
<div class="thumbImage">
<a href="images/gallery/1021141027-1431931148.jpg" data-featherlight="image">
<img src="images/gallery/1021141027-1431931148.jpg" width="200px" alt="" />
</a>
<span class="deleteImage">
<input type="hidden" value="images/gallery/1021141027-1431931148.jpg" name="delete_file" id="delete_file" />
<input type="button" value="Delete image" onclick="delete_image()"/>
</span>
</div>
```

I would like to believe the problem is this line:

```
<input type="hidden" value="images/gallery/1021141027-1431931148.jpg" name="delete_file" id="delete_file" />
```

Do you guys think it would work if it said this instead:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1021141027-1431931148.jpg" name="delete_file" id="delete_file" />
```

If this is the issue, how can I modify my gallery script to NOT include the files directory in the value.

I'm not getting any errors. I've checked my logs. Everything seems to be working just right except for the fact that the images will not delete.

EDIT: On a side note, how could I do this with checkboxes to delete multiple at once? Would that be better recommended?

Comment: It seems like maybe you're passing the external location of the file, rather than the internal.

Comment: What are the permissions on the files your trying to delete? When you script uploads the images, it may be saving them with incorrect permissions. So once they get uploaded, PHP no longer has the permissions to delete them.

Comment: Do you put more than one `<div class="thumbImage">` output on the same page?

Comment: Victor what do you mean?

Wade let me go check on that.

Riggs yes each image generated has that class.

Comment: 644 permissions on each image.

Comment: Well in that case you have more than one `<input id="delete_file" ....>` on the same page. `id's` must be unique on the page The javascript does not know which one to use or it will use the first or the last passibly  but not the one you expect

Comment: you are trying to get `$("#delete_file").val()`, but you have `id="delete_file"` in a loop, so you have `$max` number of `id`s with the same value. So how is jquery to know which one your really want?

Comment: hmm good catch. I didn't notice that.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use `onclick="delete_image('images/gallery/1021141027-1431931148.jpg')` and change the js function to use the parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
echo <input type="button" value="Delete image" onclick="delete_image()"/>'."\n";
```

change this line

```
 ?><input type="button" value="Delete image" onclick="delete_image('<?php echo $file;?>')"/>;

<?php
```

and   your script to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delete_image(value)
{
  var status = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");  
  if(status==true)
  {

    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"scripts/php/deleteImage.php",
      data:{file:value},
      success(html){
       ohSnap('Image has been deleted', 'red');
      }
    });
  }
 }
</script>
```

delete code

```
<?php
 if ( array_key_exists ('file', $_POST ) ) {
       $filename = $_POST['file'];
       if ( file_exists ( $filename ) ) {
           unlink( $filename );
           echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
       }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: Did nothing. Something is causing a fatal error. Time to investigate.

Comment: Getting same error. Also you have some letters in the first "value" backwards.

Comment: I got the jquery working. Same results though. Nothing is deleting.

Comment: check the file name is going?

Comment: I added an alert and it is getting the image name

Comment: update answer your delete file have the problem update code there and check